# Error when trying to import decision tree classifier

Tags: python, importerror

This is the error I am getting.

[image: this is the error I am getting: ImportError: cannot import name 'DecesionTreeClassifier' from 'sklearn.tree' (C:\Users\Shrey\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree_init_.py)]

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'DecesionTreeClassifier' from 'sklearn.tree' (C:\Users\Shrey  
\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\__init__.py)
```

Comment: In your cases Decesion is not correct . correct module is : from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right import statement:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
```

There is a typo error in your import statement: `DecesionTreeClassifier`

Comment: Please note that questions caused by a typo are off-topic on [so] as per the [help/on-topic]. If you find such questions, flag or vote them as off-topic, depending on your reputation. Leaving a comment on the question is sufficient if you still want to help the OP in such cases.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I will follow the same. @MisterMiyagi